# How to use filter option in InvoiceQueryRq

Tags: xml, quickbooks, qbxml

I am fetching the invoice details using InvoiceQueryRq. It fetch all the information from the quickbooks. But i need to fetch the data based on condition. How can i use filter option in InvoiceQueryRq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are a couple of examples from our [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks). We have a whole page dedicated to [example qbXML requests](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests):

**Filtering by TxnID**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="2">
      <TxnID>2484-1263499231</TxnID>
    </InvoiceQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

**Filtering by RefNumber**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="2">
            <RefNumber>1234</RefNumber> <!-- put your invoice # here -->
        </InvoiceQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

**For more examples** you should refer to the QuickBooks OSR. The QuickBooks OSR shows the full query syntax for all qbXML requests you can send to QuickBooks:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html